# Capistrano Deploy failing error for rails - bundle: not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

This is the first time I am deploying and getting errors.

here is my deploy.rb file
    require 'bundler/capistrano'
    set :application, "app"

```
set :scm, :git
set :repository,  "git@github.com:myname/#{application}.git"
set :branch, "master"

server "198.12.78.92", :web, :app, :db, primary: true
set :user, "myname"
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/public_html/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false

default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

 namespace :deploy do
   task :start do ; end
   task :stop do ; end
   task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
     run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
   end
 end
```

Here is the error I am getting.

```
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/myname/public_html/app/releases/20130313073408; true"
    servers: ["198.12.78.92"]
    [198.12.78.92] executing command
    command finished in 891ms
failed: "sh -c 'cp -RPp /home/myname/public_html/app/shared/cached-copy /home/myname/public_html/app/releases/20130313073408 && (echo dd92017bc8bb7f951df52d6a14c933e3033fd24b > /home/myname/public_html/app/releases/20130313073408/REVISION)'" on 198.12.78.92
```

EDIT - I have commented "set :deploy_via, :remote_cache" and now getting bundle: not found error though

Comment: I have a similar problem, where I get "bundle not found". I am pretty sure it has to do with the fact that I use RVM, and it is setup in .bashrc, which is not used when using the "sh" shell.  Therefore ruby and bundle is not found even thought you would find it in an interactive shell (like bash). Working on a fix but I'm no unix guru so I have no answer just yet. However use "cap deploy:check" and "cap shell" followed by "on <target> bundle" to get some informative error messages.

Answer (score 19):

OK It seems the answer is (see my comment to your question):

Have a recent rvm installed on both your workstation and the server (I have 1.17.1).

add:

```
gem 'rvm-capistrano'
```

to your Gemfile (inside group :development as the capistrano gem)

add:

```
require "rvm/capistrano"
require "bundler/capistrano"
```

to your config/deploy.rb

That should do it

Answer (score 12):

If using rbenv put this in .bashrc

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

before the following line to capistrano load the environment even if connect with non-interactive shell

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

probably will also work also with rvm initialization

Answer (score 10):

I've had the same problems. Below is solution for RBenv and RVM.

**RBENV**

Install correctly RBenv. Install bundler gem. Pefrorm 'rbenv rehash'.

Add to deploy.rb or deploy/.rb

```
set :default_environment, { 'PATH' => '$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH' }
```

**RVM**

Install correctly RVM. Install bundler gem.

```
gem 'rvm-capistrano'
```

deloy.rb or deploy/.rb

```
require 'rvm/capistrano'
set :rvm_ruby_string, 'ruby-2.0.0-p247' # Change to your ruby version
set :rvm_type, :system # :user if RVM installed in $HOME
```

For further configuration info read: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm-capistrano

Good luck.